# Paypal payment gateway for credit card/debit card

Tags: paypal, opencart, paypal-sandbox, credit-card

Is paypal providing the payment gateway that accepts payments from credit /debit cards.
I have created a sandbox account in paypal  and tried to purchase using my paypal  account and its working fine. But I need provide paypal payment gateway for customers who doesnt have paypal account. They need to purchase it by providing their account details.

Please help me on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PayPal does process credit/debit card payments without requiring your customers to have PayPal accounts. Although, you'd still need a PayPal merchant account to receive credit/debit card payments using PayPal payment gateway.